# DOJO checkedmultiselect

Tags: dojo

Hi am trying to use CheckedMultiSelect in dojo...
When i press the button all the checked items in the CheckedMultiSelect should be displayed in a textbox..Kindly Edit the code below... i tried using alertbox it did not work

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect","dijit/form/Button"]);
</script>
<script>
function selectcont()
    {
        var e=document.getElementById("multiselect");
        var str=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    }
    document.write(str);
</script>
<body class="claro">
<select multiple="true" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect" id="multiselect" >
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="VA" selected="selected">Virginia</option>
      <option value="WA" selected="selected">Washington</option>
      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
 </select>
 <div>
 <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onclick="selectcont()">click me</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Dojo 1.6    
dijit.byId("multiselect").get('value');

// Dojo >=1.7
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
   registry.byId("multiselect").get('value');
})'
```

Example Download Tests: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dijit/tests/form/test_MultiSelect.html

Docs : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect.html

Live Docs: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/MultiSelect

Comment: But how to add it to a button click event

Comment: In your specific case, you could use `var value = registry.byId('multiselect').get('value');` in your `selectcont` function and use `value` anywhere you wanted to, including as the `innerHTML` of another element. Then use `dojo/on`: `on('myButton', click, selectcont)` instead of the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I made the changes as you said,but by default i checked 2 items in the list,,the selected items are still not displayed

Comment: I used forloop for multiple selection in the list and got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank You All..
I got the desired Output:

```
<!-- DOKO-CHECKED MULTI SELECT -->
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<style type="text/css">
@import "dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css";
    </style>
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect"]); 
</script>
<script>
function hop()
    {
            var total="";
            var a=document.getElementById("multiselect").options;
            var b=a.length;
             var values = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i < b; i++)
        {
            if(a[i].selected)
            values[i]=a[i].value;

        }
            if(values=="")
            alert("select Items")
            else
            document.getElementById("name").value=values;
    }
</script>
<body class="claro">
<h1>DRUG INDICATIONS</h1>
<select multiple="true" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" id="multiselect" >
      <option  value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
      <option  value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
      <option  value="Washington">Washington</option>
      <option  value="Florida">Florida</option>
      <option  value="California">California</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" name="goto" onClick="hop()" value="ADD">
 <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="name" id="name">
 </body>
</html>
```

-Regards,
Deepak.